# Portable way to read data from stdin without blocking

Tags: c, asynchronous, stream, stdin

Is there a portable way to read data from `stdin` without blocking, or to check if data is available to be read without blocking? Keep in mind stdin could be piped from another process, not just be terminal/keyboard input.

Best would be only using ANSI C function from stdlib.h or stdio.h, but using POSIX functions would be very portable too.

Also I'm not sure about this, but there are [some forum posts](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/285863-non-blocking-stdin-read-on-win32/) where they say `select()` wouldn't work on Windows in practice.

Comment: could you mention the cause or your case I never get the scanf blocked

Comment: I recall something about peek and found this through a bit of googling, might be something there that works. http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t318260-peek-at-stdin-flush-stdin.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101079/making-stdin-non-blocking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select()` and `poll()` are the POSIX way, but they won't work on Windows for non-sockets.

If Windows and Unix are both your targets, there's no way portable enough. Even more, on Windows you have to handle pipes and console handles separately: `PeekNamedPipe()` for pipes, `PeekConsoleInput()` for console (and it's rather complicated with the latter even if you don't have `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`, turning to a real can of worms if you do).

Doing input in a separate thread is more portable, even with pthread vs. Windows differences (and there are pthread-for-Win32 libraries to get rid of those differences).