# How to read ANSI DSR Query Responses in Rust

Tags: rust, ansi-escape

I'm looking for a pure rust solution which either uses Rust's stdlib or doesn't utilize a crate with libc.

One example of a Device Status Report ([DSR](https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DSR.html)) is a simple query to find the current size of a terminal in width and height.  First a `CSI` request:  `ESC` + `[`.  Then a command of `19` and finally a termination character of `t`.  For example:  `\x1b[19t`.  The terminal will then respond with another `CSI`: `ESC` + `[`, a status identifier, `9` and then the `row count` followed by the `column count` and a terminating character, `t`.  For an 80x25 terminal, the response would look like: `\x1b[9;25;80t`.

In Rust, it is rather straight-forward to send a request to the terminal using a `print!` macro call:

```rust
print!("\x1b[19t");
```

Alternatively, in a shell, one might run:

```sh
$ printf "\x1b[19t"
```

However, I've been unable to actually capture the response coming back from the terminal.  This is not my initial approach, but it is supposedly the one that provides me with a non-blocking stdin read (based on experimentation, it is not non-blocking), which is something [I'm expecting that I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026858/reading-the-device-status-report-ansi-escape-sequence-reply).

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, TryRecvError};
use std::{
    io::{self, Read},
    thread, time,
};

fn main() {
    let timeout = time::Duration::from_micros(50);
    let rx = spawn_read();
    print!("\x1b[19t");
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..200 {
        thread::sleep(timeout);
        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(value) => data.push(value),
            Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {}
            Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => break,
        }
    }
    let string = match std::str::from_utf8(&data) {
        Ok(value) => value,
        Err(_why) => "",
    };
    println!("Captured: {:?}", string);
}

fn spawn_read() -> Receiver<u8> {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<u8>();
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let mut buf = [0u8];
        io::stdin().read_exact(&mut buf).unwrap();
        if buf != [0u8] {
            tx.send(buf[0]).ok();
        }
    });
    rx
}
```

Running the above, I see:

```
Captured: ""
```

But with the code above, I expect (some flavor of `CSI` `9` `;` `<rows>` `;` `<cols>` `t`):

```
Captured: "\x1b[9;25;80t"
```

Comment: Is using the libc crate ok? Without it one needs to define a bunch of types to get `tcsetattr` to work.

Comment: Actually those are not "ANSI", because that refers to ECMA-48 which doesn't do those sequences.  This particular one comes from xterm (see [documentation](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Miscellaneous)), and isn't a "DSR" sequence.

Comment: @HHK are you able to point me to where those types might be?  Is there an example in code somewhere (I guess I'm really looking for Rust, though I suppose I could go poke around at the existing LibC code).

Comment: Typos in question: 9 is maximize (19 is screensize).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Can you be more specific?  Are you suggesting that the captured response should be `\x1b[19;25;80t`?  I ask because my terminal program returns `9` there, not `19`... I've been pecking at differing documentation all over and it seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: The way in which your question is written makes it less clear than the comment (which happens to agree with [this](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps;Ps;Ps-t:Ps-=-1-9.2069)).  But if the Rust code is returning no response, I'd look to see what device it's actually reading.

Comment: To be more clear:  I'm using [iterm2](https://iterm2.com/) for my terminal.  And the question's expected response above reflects the actual response I get from iterm2 when I run a `printf`.  I believe HHK was correct; I need to run `tcsetattr` and/or put the terminal in "raw" mode before I can query the terminal's response.  Rust doesn't have a native std library that can do this; we have to dip into [libc](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc).  Rust has difficulty with multiple versions of any library that uses C underneath, so I wanted to avoid c-libraries.